# Multiple stun/turn servers on Kurento/elasticRTC

Tags: webrtc, kurento

Is it possible (or any hack) to configure multiple stun/turn servers on the WebRtcEndpoint.conf.ini or through our signaling servers? So that if one stun fails it falls back to another? If the feature is not available what would be the closest solution?

I am not sure if I am looking into the right location - I've seen that WebRtcEndpoint has methods for- getStunServerPort()/getStunServerAddress(). So a possible client side configuration?

*Reason - We've been using kurento media server (6.0) and elasticRTC 6.5 (For the future development) on an AWS vpc. It was working fine by using one of the publicly available STUN servers. Suddenly it stopped working and we figured out the STUN server was not working anymore. So we switched to Google stun and it started working normally*

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest, instead of using a globally configured IP in `WebRtcEndpoint.conf.ini`, to use the methods that you mention in the `WebRtcEndpoint`. That way, you can use a CNAME and resolve the IP every now and then. You might have a separate scheduled task that checks the STUN server to see if it's still available, and then refresh it when it is no longer valid.

Comment: hi ivan, sorry for cross posting, but can you please take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/q/41919022/3326331 post

Comment: Hey @igracia, Sorry I am not able to completely understand it. So you mean to say there should not be any entry for turnURL in `WebRtcEndpoint.conf.ini`? Do you have an example of one KMS using multiple turn servers?