# ProtocolException in getChildren()

Tags: java, kurento

When I try to call `getChildren()` on the `mediapipeline` which has my custom module endpoint running in it I'm getting this exception:

> org.kurento.client.internal.server.ProtocolException: Exception
>   creating Java Class for mycustomfilter.MyCustomFilter

This is the code which triggers it:

```
List<MediaObject> mediaObjects = pipelines.get(i).getChildren();
```

Do I have to cast the `List<MediaObject>` to some other data type?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you create a custom media element for KMS, you can also create the client API for Java and JavaScript (see doc [here](http://doc-kurento.readthedocs.io/en/stable/mastering/develop_kurento_modules.html)). In your case, you need to create the Java client for your filter, as follows:

```
cmake .. -DGENERATE_JAVA_CLIENT_PROJECT=TRUE
```

The resulting Java classes (package `mycustomfilter.MyCustomFilter` in your example) should be in the classpath of the project which calls to `getChildren()` (internally it calls to `Class.forName`, see code [here](https://github.com/Kurento/kurento-java/blob/master/kurento-client/src/main/java/org/kurento/client/internal/transport/serialization/ModuleClassesManager.java)).

Comment: thats correct, but what if I want to access such a KMS with custom module of which I don't have the `jar`. As these custom modules may inherit `FilterImpl` or `HubImpl` isn't it possible to cast the custom module directly into parent classes ?

Comment: You can still use that module even if you don't have the JAR. But it that case you will need to speak directly the Kurento protocol (see info [here](http://doc-kurento.readthedocs.io/en/stable/mastering/kurento_protocol.html)) with KMS (i.e. JSON-RPC messages). But for the best of my knowledge, if you don't have the JAR, the initial problem (exception when calling to `getChildren()`) cannot be solved.

Answer (score 0):

Could you try this?

```
List<MediaObject> mediaObjects = new ArrayList<MediaObject>(Arrays.asList(pipelines.get(i).getChildren()));
```